# count list values that appears in dataFrame using python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to count list value that is exists in dataframe:

I want to use a loop to go through list values and dataframe df and if list[0] exist in df count++.

my code:
df = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\ma\Desktop\filee')
df looks like this :

| Intents | Examples |
| --- | --- |
| First | something |
| Second | something |

listX= ["HOFF", "Customers", "bank"]

I did this but not working:

```
count = 0
for i in listX[0]:
for x in df['Examples']:
    if x.str.contains(i):
       count++
```

Comment: Do you have a question or just felt like sharing?

Comment: If it's a question don't forget to post your code and explain what was wrong with it.

Comment: Do you want to match the whole list or just some values with the df, and kindly post samples of list and your df for clarity

Comment: yeah i have, well I read an excel sheet and saved it in dataframe as df, then created a list list= ["y", "z", "x"]. now i want to go through both of them,  count=0
for i in list[0]:
for y in df:
if i == y:
     count++:

Comment: @Sardar Arslan, some thats why i used list[0]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you don't want to use loops with pandas. Its not the way the API was intended to be used. You would probably want to use pandas lambda functions since they are easy to understand and will get you started on the right path. The following will check to see if items in ListX match the items in the Example column. Keep in mind, I am assuming the datatype of the Example column is a list and not a string.

```
listX= ["HOFF", "Customers", "bank"]

# define the function that will give you the desired output
def count_items(examples):
    matching_items = [examples.index(x) for x in listX]
    return len(matching_items)

# then execute the function you defined with a lambda expression
# you pass in the values you wish to pass into the function
# axis = 1 means you want to loop over rows not columns
df['Count'] = df.apply(lambda x: count_items(x["Examples"]), axis = 1)
```

If you need to split the string value of the example column to a list, use the .split() function:

```
s = '1,2,3'
list = s.split(',')
print(list)    # prints ['1', '2', '3']
```

You can add this logic into your count_items function, before matching the items. This way the value is in the correct datatype (list)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I got this error: ValueError: substring not found. 
do you know why?

Comment: As stated in the answer, you probably need to convert the Examples column value to a list. Its probably being read as a single string. You need to use the .split() function and pass in a comma to tell the function what to split by:     
s = '1,2,3'
list = s.split(',')
print(list)    # prints ['1', '2', '3']

Comment: I have modified the answer to help you out. Please mark as answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the below mthod you can match the list value with the column value of your dataframe.

Don't use the name list for your list, give it some other name.

You can't loop through the entire dataframe, so use the code below to loop through columns instead.

There are better ways to do this though, but the below is one way.

```
count=0
for x in list:
    for y in df.column.tolist():
         if x==y:
             count+=1
``
```